# Hibernate auto generated <generator class="increment" /> in hbm files

Tags: java, xml, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I am building a web application using JSF 2.2 and Hibernate 4.3.11 versions.

I have perfectly generated my POJO classes and mapped `hbm.xml` files using the Eclipse Hibernate code generation tool.

However, in the `hbm.xml` file, the default generator class for primary keys is "assigned" which requires users to set id value on their own.

On the other hand my target is to set primary key sequences incrementally by Hibernate using `<generator class="increment" />`

Is there any way to generate `hbm.xml` automatically with "increment" value?

It is not really possible to change all +100 `hbm.xml` files from "assigned" to "increment" after each code generation.

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate can use the database features like @@identity in ms-sql or seq.nextval in oracle.
But, if you have to use the hibernate increment, must know that is not usefull. Because before insert each record in table , hibernate must find max id in your table.that means hibernate execute "select max(id) from table". And you can change it.
In concurrent process you have dead lock an uniqe constrante error.

Regards a.ayati